# Why use GC.Collect here?

Tags: c#, garbage-collection

I know this has been asked a zillion times before, and I know the prevalent answer is "don't do it", which, from my limited knowledge, I totally support. However, I am working on someone else's code and he happens to use GC.Collect in a situation in which I can hardly see any use for it. I am still giving the coder the benefit of the doubt, and perhaps someone can explain him what his intention was. Needless to say, this coder is not available, he just used to work in my company and I happened to inherit his code.

So basically I have a class, for which he implemented a Dispose() method(see at the end of the code), and he calls GC.Collect inside it. The class has a method for generating a CSV file from a datatable, and the StreamWriter.Close() is properly called at the end of the method. Nevermind the inheritance from class ErrorManager, it barely contains two members(string and int) and does some basic operations with them.

```
public class ExportCSV : ErrorManager
{
    public ExportCSV(TypeUser type) { }

    public string CreateCSV(DataTable dt, string fileName)
    {
        string retval = "";
        retval = fileName;

        StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fileName, false);

        try
        {
            int iColCount = dt.Columns.Count;

            // Scrive i nomi dei campi nella prima RIGA.
            for (int i = 0; i < iColCount; i++)
            {
                sw.Write(dt.Columns[i]);
                if (i < iColCount - 1)
                {
                    sw.Write(",");
                }
            }
            sw.Write(sw.NewLine);

            // Now write all the rows.
            foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < iColCount; i++)
                {
                    if (!Convert.IsDBNull(dr[i]))
                    {
                        if (dt.Columns[i].DataType == typeof(string))
                            sw.Write("\"" + dr[i].ToString().Replace("\"", "\"\"") + "\"");
                        else
                            sw.Write(dr[i].ToString().Replace(",", "."));

                        //Scrive il valore del campo
                        sw.Write(dr[i].ToString());

                    }
                    if (i < iColCount - 1)
                    {
                        sw.Write(",");
                    }
                }
                sw.Write(sw.NewLine);
            }
            sw.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ErrorCode = 1;
            ErrorDescription = ex.Message;
            retval = "";
        }
        finally
        {
            sw.Close();
        }

        return retval;
    }

    #region Dispose Members

    public void Dispose()
    {
        GC.Collect();
    }

    #endregion
}
```

So my question is just, what on earth is the GC.Collect() doing here???

Sorry for any flaws in my question, I have used stackoverflow for a long time to search other's questions, but I have barely asked anything myself before.

Comment: I guess, only *that developer* can tell you why, otherwise there shouldn't be any reason of doing that.

Comment: There's no reason. StreamWriter will clean up on its own, and garbage collect will go off at the appropriate time.  I'm guessing he came from a programming background that didn't do automatic garbage collection so he is used to adding this to a dispose method

Comment: Given the fact that the writer of this code didn't put the `StreamWriter` in a `using` statement, I would guess they did not fully understand what they were doing either.

Comment: The `IDisposable` interface is not even related to collecting managed memory so this is most likely cargo cult code.

Comment: @juharr He's using a try/finally to dispose of it, and he did it properly.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it requires reading the mind of another developer.

Comment: There are so many things in this code that say "not an experienced C# developer" that my guess would be that the developer misunderstood what a `GC.Collect` does or when to use it.

Comment: A possibility is that the developpper experienced out of memory exceptions in his application and that he scattered GC.Collect() instructions in the main procedures to fix the memory problem.

Comment: Thanks for all your comments, which reinforce my initial astonishment at this. Being this class part of an API, I have decided to leave it as it is, but I won't actually call Dispose() in my application. Trying not to mess with the previous code, but no need to bring seemingly unnecessary stuff to mine.

Comment: By the way, I have just noticed, why is he calling sw.Close() at the end of the try block and also inside the finally block. I don't see the point either but I am not an experienced C# developer, so I thought I might well ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's **just** about possible that this made sense. Well, "made sense" is overly generous, but it might have fixed something.

**If** the objects created by reading through the `DataTable` and creating strings based on them was very large in number, and **if** a large batch of these `CreateCSV()` operations happened in close succession and **if** these `CreateCSV()` operations were called on different instances of `ExportCSV` which were then each `Dispose`d of (whether explicitly or via `using`) then this call to `GC.Collect()` might seem to magically speed things up or prevent out of memory issues.

In such a case where you have code suddenly creating a lot of objects you can sometimes end up with cases where the spike in objects being allocated and then available for garbage collection outpaces what the GC is expecting. And when that happens periodically calling `GC.Collect()` explicitly can be beneficial. This is rare, but it can be one of the few cases where explicit collection is necessary. (Simple test; if your machine doesn't grind to a halt without it, then it isn't necessary).

Now consider:

```
for(var i = 0; i != someLargeNumber; ++i)
{
  var table = GetTablesFromSomeSource();
  var fileName = GetFileNamesFromSomeSource();
  using(var exporter = new ExportCSV(someArgument))
  {
    exporter.CreateCSV(table, fileName);
  } // `Dispose()` called here, calling GC.Collect()
}
```

If this was the case, then the fact that the cycle of different `ExportCSV` instances being disposed would mean that `GC.Collect()` was being called periodically could have fixed things. It would be no different if it was called somewhere else in the loop. Indeed somewhere else in the loop would be better; as well as being more controllable (you could add a count so as to not call it every single loop) it's being called closer to the actual logic that's requiring it (the need relates to there being a loop which in turn involves a lot of allocation and release, not to the object being disposed).

For extra fun, someone coming along and looking at the code in `ExportCSV` and seeing the `GC.Collect()` in the `Dispose()` as pointless and removing it would then cause the memory issue of such a spike in use to recur. Then they'd put the `GC.Collect()` back in and it would magically fix the issue. `GC.Collect()` would have become a ["more magic" switch](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/magic-story.html).

That possibility is marginal. If it is the case, I suggest moving the `GC.Collect()` to where it really belongs. I also suggest trying something like `if(++loopCount % someNumber == 0){GC.Collect();}` to reduce the number of calls; the higher `someNumber` the less unnecessary calls but the greater risk of triggering the memory problems the explicit calls are there to prevent, with the optimum best found by profiling on real data.

On the other hand, it may just be that they didn't really get that garbage collection and disposal are very different things, along the lines of several questions you can find here from people who start off thinking that `Dispose()` has something to do with freeing managed memory, and it seemed like a good idea on that basis. In this case it's hurting GC performance for no reason; just take it out. If the class isn't public to an API then take out the unnecessary `IDisposable` implementation entirely, though that's a breaking change if it is public to an API.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Many of the other answers were also useful, but I marked this one as answer because it was the most extensive one.

Comment: In fact it is part of an API, which is the main reason why I didn't want to mess with it. Anyway, in my application, I am only calling ExportCSV up to 5 times, so it shouldn't bring big memory consumption. On an effort to be as neutral as possible, I will leave the IDisposable implementation as it is, so as to not mess with the API, but I won't actually call Dispose() in my code.

Comment: I'd certainly consider taking the `GC.Collect()` call out of the dispose. As you say it's part of an API, I'd leave the no-op `Dispose()` because taking that out is a breaking change, but removing the bogus `GC.Collect()` wouldn't be.

Answer (score 3):

Wow. There isn't even a *semblance* of a reason. The class doesn't even have any fields or anything!

I suppose someone was trying to mimic deterministic memory management used in e.g. C++. The only use this has whatsoever is to ensure the memory is released *sooner* - something that's rarely needed nowadays. If the application does anything besides this, it's probably going to be reclaimed soon enough.

So unless you're absolutely willing to trade CPU and latency for a bit of extra memory, just don't bother and get rid of the `Dispose`, as well as the `GC.Collect` call. But it might be worth it to avoid creating tons of unnecessary objects in the first place - `dr[i].ToString().Replace(",", ".")` are *awesome* at breaking your application in subtle ways, as well as being rather inefficient.

Comment: Exactly, the absence of fields was my first reason for suspicion.

Answer (score 1):

I guess he doesn't really know what he's doing. Even if he'd want to immediately collect the instance which is being disposed, it would not happen with that call, because you still have a reference to it (from where you call the `Dispose` method)

Comment: Not necessarily. It's possible to collect an object while one of its methods is running, as long as that method has no subsequent use of `this` and the caller doesn't subsequently use the object. It's unlikely, but it is possible.

Comment: @JonHanna interesting.

Comment: If the object's fields or virtual members aren't going to be used again then the storage on the stack and/or in registers that references it can be used for something else. If that happens and the GC does a sweep at that point, it will find the object to be collectable. It can then collect the object while a method is still running. This won't hurt anything because the same fact that no field or virtual member is used means any code in such a method won't care. The few places that need `GC.KeepAlive()` are to prevent the few cases where it actually does matter, such as timers waiting a trigger

Answer (score 1):

only one reason. this line;

```
StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fileName, false);
```

developer could not find way to use using block in try block and he/she hope GC will help him/her. no.

```
using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fileName, false))
{

}
```

and he/she add finaly block. sw.Dispose()

note: I worked many bug fix projects. do not give special meaning for every code block. sometime it could be "developer" reason.

look this block.

```
    ErrorCode = 1;
    ErrorDescription = ex.Message;
    retval = "";
```

What it means? catch any reason and set your Error object property, do you really interested why you can not write file or real error you could not write on a file? no reason.